# Angular 1.x with TypeScript 2.x, @types, and SystemJS - Using global typings

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

I am trying to use Angular 1.x with the new TS2 and @types registry but running into problems. It looks like @types does not use what the typings registry refered to as "global" typings. I am running into the following error:

```
error TS2686: 'angular' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.
```

The angular code is as following:

```
import "angular";
import "angular-route";

const app = angular.module("charter-app", ["ui.bootstrap", "ui.router", "templates", "charter-app.controllers"]);
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "inlineSources": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types/" ],
    "types": [ "angular", "angular-ui-bootstrap", "angular-ui-router" ],
    "outFile": "app.js"
    }
 }
```

Trying to use the following

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/angular": "^1.5.20",
    "@types/angular-ui-bootstrap": "^0.13.35",
    "@types/angular-ui-router": "^1.1.34",
```

I'm using gulp-typescript to do the compilation. What am I missing? Can I not use the @types libraries for this purpose?

Answer (score 59):

I can think of 2 approaches here.

**1) Mark angular as [global](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html)**. *(Much easier migration option)*

Create a `d.ts` file say `overrides.d.ts` and do:

```
declare global {
  const angular: ng.IAngularStatic;
}
export {};
```

or

```
import * as _angular_ from 'angular';

declare global {
  const angular: typeof _angular_;
}
```

and that's it, no need to `import` or manage script loading separately for this.

**2) Import it in every impacted file.** *(May be more tedious migration option on a large existing project)*

If you can go ahead update all the impacted files (Usually a bit hard to take this approach in a much big project which already has lots of error related to this) where ever you refer to `angular`, import it:

```
import * as angular from "angular";
```

If you are taking this approach, typescript will transpile with `angular` as a dependency for the file and your module loader (eg: `SystemJS`) needs to handle the import. This may be done either by having systemJS manage the imports via maps/paths or if the script is loaded by `script` tags then you can create a fake module for `angular` by using **[`SystemJS.registerDynamic` or `SystemJS.set`](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/system-api.md#systemjsregisterdynamicname--deps-declare)** apis.

Comment: You are currect. 10x for this answer you solved me the problem

Comment: This sovled an issue I had trying to import fabricjs.  Thanks

Comment: @PSL where to put the file for the approach 1) ?

Comment: @eXavier You can place it anywhere in your app root.

Comment: I am trying this, but I get `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './angular' in 'C:\...\node_modules\angular'`

Answer (score 4):

Add this import to your code

```
import * as angular from "angularjs";
```

See [Typescript Angular Import](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10638) for more information

Comment: I ended up relegating back to typings. I trying this syntax but still had errors.

Comment: I get the following error when trying to do this with Lodash:

Error in System.import, could not bootstrap. Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/lodash
 Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/lodash
 Error loading http://172.16.95.136:3000/lodash as "lodash" from http://localhost:3000/proj/src/app/app(anonymous function) @ localhost/:52

Answer (score 1):

I was building a file watcher for the Webstorm IDE and ran into this problem.  To solve it, I had to remove `@types/angular`, add `typings angular` also include `typings angular` in my compilation by adding the option: 
`--types {your file dir}/typings/index.d.ts`.  Similarly, you can add that to your `tsconfig.json`

I know this is not the solution you were hoping for, but it got me over that hump.