# Typescript, remove error Error:(54, 33) TS2686:'fabric' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

So I am getting this error:

```
import {Canvas} from "fabric";
```

> Error:(54, 33) TS2686:'fabric' refers to a UMD global, but the current
>   file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.

I am using fabric in Angular project with TypeScript.
It is being imported manually into the project via angular-cli.

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
        "./libs/jquery.base64.js",
        "./store/signage_sdk.js",
        "../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js",
```

I am also using `@types/fabric`

how I can quiet this error?

tx

Sean

Comment: You should not get that error if you import (in every file where `fabric` is referenced) like you mentioned in your question. Is the error coming from the same file or from a different file? Also you can mark `fabric` as global and avoid doing an import as it is a global anyway. This [answer might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40664298/angular-1-x-with-typescript-2-x-types-and-systemjs-using-global-typings/42035067#42035067)?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this answers your question but I think it might help you to resolve your problem. Unfortunately I still don't have the reputation to write it as a comment, so here is an "answer".

I dealt with the same error this week. I use React though. In my case the problem was that TSLink suggested me to remove unused imports from my files and in one case the import was React itself. So even though React was not needed, ReactDOM, which I used in that file, wanted it implicitly.

As a result, when I used the ReactDOM properties, they were throwing the same error as in your case, only in my case it was "React" instead of "Fabric".

I also use the typings for these modules.

Regards

Comment: And the resolution being?

Answer (score 0):

Try add

```
import * as fabric from "fabric";
```

on the top of the file, and reference `Canvas` as `fabric.Canvas`:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById("test_canvas") as HTMLCanvasElement;
const fabricCanvas = new fabric.Canvas(canvas);
```

Also, use

```
// ReSharper disable once WrongRequireRelativePath
```

if Resharper complains about the path.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
import { fabric } from 'fabric'
```

Then use

```
new fabric.Canvas()
```

That should work and quiet the error.