# TypeScript no longer resolves any modules, user or installed

Tags: typescript

I was having no problems, and then yesterday I ran npm update, and something broke that I can't figure out.*(see **update 2**)

At the top of my source TypeScript JSX files, ES modules, I have the following lines:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Which is where the resolution error first appears in Intellisense, with 'react' underlined in red, and the following hover tag, with the same result for my user modules (module name prefixed by './'), they say:

```
"Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)".
```

If I run the TypeScript compiler, the error appears to be

```
"error TS2686: 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead."
```

Which is not what I expected because I thought the UMD modules auto detect what's calling it, so it can be imported or required.
Why is it saying I'm not importing it?*(See **update 3**)
The tsc errors don't appear for every file, only where the React components are included in the ReactDom.createRoot().render() main file.

When I set "explainFiles" to true, TypeScript compiler outputs the react and react-dom modules, as well as user import files, correctly--belying the Intellisense message that it couldn't find them.

When I set "listFiles" to true, tsc outputs all the right @types files I import.

VS Code about:

```
Version: 1.76.2 (user setup)
Commit: ee2b180d582a7f601fa6ecfdad8d9fd269ab1884
Date: 2023-03-14T17:55:54.936Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
Sandboxed: Yes
```

package.json:

```
 {
    "name": "test-webpacking",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "description": "",
    "main": "test.js",
    "typings": "test.d.ts",
    "scripts": {
     "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "basic developer",
    "license": "ISC",
    "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.3",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.2",
    "webpack": "^5.76.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.13.1"
   },
    "dependencies": {
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.7.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
   }
 }
```

tsconfig.json:

```
 {
     "compilerOptions": {
     "outDir":"src/js",
     "target": "es6", 
     "lib": ["dom"],
     "jsx": "react",
     "module": "ES2021"
     "moduleResolution": "node",
     "isolatedModules": true, 
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true, 
     "strict": true,
     }
 }
```

The TypeScript configuration setting, "moduleResolution", had already been set to node, so that wasn't the problem for me.
Also, restarting VS Code, and the computer didn't solve it.

While editing the TypeScript file, the bottom of the editor says its using TypeScript JSX.

I tried deleting the node_modules folder, along with the package-lock.json file, and ran Node package manager install, with the same result.

I tried updating TypeScript, and even Node, to the latest versions, to no avail.

**Update**: per @nekooee's answer, I tried to temporarily solve my problem.
I restored the package-lock.json, and package.json file from git repo and executed

```
npm install --save-exact
```

But the typescript errors persisted.

I downgraded react, @types/react, react-dom, @types/react-dom and TypeScript, with no success, and
then re-upgraded, but typescript won't find anything imported still.

**Update 2**: Apparently there were VS Code extensions that I needed, now the Intellisense errors disappeared, but the TS compiler error (TS2686), regarding the UMD global reportedly not being imported, persists.

**Update 3**: The TS2686 error was resolved via a fix in comments to [Typescript, remove error Error:(54, 33) TS2686:'fabric' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41574002/2657368) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the tutorial, [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/wsl-vscode)
Microsoft implies VS Code works to some degree without the WSL extension, but

> We do not recommend using WSL in VS Code without the WSL extension as
> you will lose support for auto-complete, debugging, linting, etc.

VS Code can work in a WSL-based project without the extension for it, but it stops working at some point apparently, then you need the WSL extension for TypeScript and Intellisense to work.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem today after updating the typescript to v5. I don't know if this is a bug or not. I also get errors in import quasar. Anyway, I downgraded Typescript to version 4.9.5 to find more documentation on this and my problem was solved.

Comment: I tried this, no fix for me.