# typescript importing wrong angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-mock

I am importing angular in my angular 1 app (in typescript) using syntax like below

```
   import * as angular from 'angular';
```

This imports angular from `angular-mocks` and not from `angular` because of which my ILogService implementation fails

> ERROR in ./app/shared/Logger.factory.ts (38,7): error TS2420: Class
>   'Logger' incorrectly implements interface 'ILogService'.   Types of
>   property 'debug' are incompatible.
>       Type '(...argument: any[]) => void' is not assignable to type 'ILogCall'.

Even when I try to navigate to `'angular'` from `vscode` I get navigated to angular-mocks angular definition. It should get navigated to angular and not to mock library...

How to avoid this problem?

**EDIT**

Below is the implementation of

The implementation I have is custom service about which typescript gives an error during compilation (the error is pasted above)

```
class Logger implements ng.ILogService {
     info(message:string) { //some custom logic in info method}
}

angular.service('logger', Logger)
```

Comment: *because of which my ILogService implementation fails* - which implementation? Please, provide all code that is necessary to replicate the problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . *This imports angular from angular-mocks and not from angular* - where did this conclusion come from? The way how VS Code navigates between classes affects only the way how it navigates, nothing else.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40664298/4110233. The answers are here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused because angular-mock's typing is an augmentation to angular's. In other words, a real ILogCall interface should be:

```
interface ILogCall {
    (...args: any[]): void;   //from @types\angular\index.d.ts
    logs: string[];    //from @types\angular-mocks\index.d.ts
}
```

So in your code:

```
info(message:string) { //some custom logic in info method}
```

you need to return a correct ILogCall object(with all **members**). @TheChetan and @Natarajan Nagarajugari 's answer may be helpful, but I am not sure whether it would break your TypeScript writing unit tests.

My solution is in info(message:string):

```
info(message:string)
{
    var logCall: any = (...args: any[]) => {};
    logCall.logs = //something;

    return logCall as ng.ILogCall;
}
```

Comment: so if I am not wrong, you are suggesting to implement both interfaces

Comment: this is kind of OK solution, but is there a way where I can disable loading of definitions from angular-mocks

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
import * as _angular_ from 'angular';

declare global {
const angular: typeof _angular_;
}
```

Hope it would help you

Comment: it would be helpful if you can explain this answer as to why it will work